# Keep reading data while updating GUI tkinter in a non blocking way

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio, pyserial

I'm new to asyncio, threading, subrocess and I'm trying to build an app that reads data from the serial continuesly, put them inot a queue used by another process/thread/asyncio function to consume them and show into a tkinter GUI.

I was able to make the GUI non blocking while continue reading the data with the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import queue
import logging
import serial
import sys


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.serial_text_label = tk.Label(self, text="String")
        self.serial_text_label.pack()
        self.serial_text = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=21)
        self.serial_text.pack()

        self.port = 'COM3'
        self.baud = 38400

        self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baud, timeout=0)
        if self.ser.isOpen():
            self.ser.close()
            self.ser.open()

        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()

        logging.info("created serial port")

        # start the serial_text_label "ticking"
        self.update_screen()

    def update_screen(self):

        self.serial_text.delete('1.0', tk.END)

        data = ""
        data_raw = self.ser.read(1)
        if data_raw == b'\x02':
            data_raw = self.ser.read(6)
            data = "02-" + str(data_raw.hex('-'))
            self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
            self.ser.reset_output_buffer()

        self.serial_text.insert(tk.END, data)
        # self.serial_text_label.configure(text=data)

        # call this function again when want to refresh
        self.after(500, self.update_screen)


if __name__== "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d)', )

    app = SampleApp()

    app.mainloop()
```

The only issue with my code is that all the reading and the elaboration of thedata coming from the serial port are inside the refresh cycle that update the screen. I would like to detach the function to some sort of thread/subprocess that works concurrently with the refresh of the GUI.

What I've tried is to create an `async def do_serial()` function inside  `class SampleApp(tk.Tk)` as below:

```
async def do_serial():
    logging.debug("do serial")

    data = ""
    data_raw = ser.read(1)
    if data_raw == b'\x02':
        data_raw = ser.read(6)
        data = "02-" + str(data_raw.hex('-'))
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        ser.reset_output_buffer()

    # add data to queue
    if data != "":
        logging.debug('put:' + str(data))
        incoming_serial_queue.put(data)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

and inside the `update_screen` function I call `asyncio.run(do_serial())`

```
    if not incoming_serial_queue.empty():
        data = incoming_serial_queue.get()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and the code doesn't even show the GUI

Is there a way to process the data from the serial in an asyncronus/parallel way without having to write all the function inside the refresh GUI function?

Comment: You're using a blocking queue inside of `async` function. That is not how it supposed to work. Try `asyncio.Queue` instead.

Comment: for those who just want a simple answer, you can refer to this [minimal example](https://codeahoy.com/learn/tkinter/ch5/#basic-thread-stuffz). Threading might be a good way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a blocking calls in a separate thread. Inside update_screen, you should make calls fast enough to not no freeze GUI. That means, you should not read the input there.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time
import queue
import logging
import serial
import sys
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.serial_text_label = tk.Label(self, text="String")
        self.serial_text_label.pack()
        self.serial_text = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=21)
        self.serial_text.pack()

        self.port = 'COM3'
        self.baud = 38400

        self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baud, timeout=0)
        if self.ser.isOpen():
            self.ser.close()
            self.ser.open()

        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()

        logging.info("created serial port")

        # start the serial_text_label "ticking"
        self._update_scheduled = threading.Condition()
        self._terminating = threading.Event()
        self.update_screen()
    
    def mainloop(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            future = executor.submit(self._do_update_screen_loop)
            try:
                return super().mainloop()
            finally:
                # letting the thread to know we're done
                self._terminating.set()
                with self._update_scheduled:
                    self._update_scheduled.notify_all()

    def update_screen(self):
        with self._update_scheduled:
            self._update_scheduled.notify_all()
        self.after(500, self.update_screen)

    def _do_update_screen_loop(self):
        while True:
            with self._update_scheduled:
                self._update_scheduled.wait()
            if self._terminating.is_set():
                return
            self._do_update_screen()

    def _do_update_screen(self):            
        self.serial_text.delete('1.0', tk.END)

        data = ""
        data_raw = self.ser.read(1)
        if data_raw == b'\x02':
            data_raw = self.ser.read(6)
            data = "02-" + str(data_raw.hex('-'))
            self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
            self.ser.reset_output_buffer()

        self.serial_text.insert(tk.END, data)
        # self.serial_text_label.configure(text=data)


if __name__== "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d)', )

    app = SampleApp()
        
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your new `SampleApp()` needs `executor`

Comment: it returns `RuntimeError: cannot notify on un-acquired lock` in  `line 48, in update_screen self._update_scheduled.notify_all()`

Comment: And fixed that too

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that in a hurry, didn't test it at all

Comment: @NicoCaldo, pls check out the latest version of snippet. It releases the lock before calling ` _do_update_screen()` to prevent possible freezes when serial IO is slow.

Comment: What if I need to update the label in the blocking call? For example, I want to download a file in the background, then display a label showing the download progress, updated every second. I also have to stop updating after the download is complete (i.e. the downloaded filesize matches the total filesize)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would use `root.mainloop()` as the funtion, but for async, you'll have to use something else, however you'll have to create a loop yourself if you want the window to update every frame. The async function is simply `root.update()`.

Hope this helped!